# Fast Ruby but slow Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

1. Why is `rails --version` command much slower than `ruby --version`?
2. Can we make `rails` command fast as `ruby` command?

On Windows 8, the `ruby --version` command runs without delay but `rails --version` takes some time (a few seconds).

Comment: Maybe because Rails loads its own libraries that are not included in Ruby. So it takes more time. What is *very slower* and *some time*? A second, an hour?

Comment: For the first time , rails --version" command takes two-three seconds to run and then take 1 second.Can we build/convert "rails and its own libraries" to windows executable file?

Comment: Rails loads a *lot* of libraries when you invoke it. There's been some good work done lately on Rubygems that improves load times of libraries, but Ruby's loading semantics unfortunately make `require` a rather slow operation once you have a lot of libraries installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.Why "rails" command is very slower than "ruby"?

`ruby` invokes the Ruby interpreter, which is a compiled executable.

`rails` invokes the Ruby interpreter *plus* loads many Ruby libraries that need to be located then parsed by the interpreter, before executing your Rails command. So `rails --version` will *always* take longer than `ruby --version` because it does the same as it plus more.

> 2.Can we make "rails" command fast as "ruby" command?

Not easily, but this is not usually considered a priority performance issue, because the library loading typically happens once per process - meaning web server requests are not delayed by it, just server start-up time.

Ruby and Rails programs can and do have real performance issues that are normally better to focus on. For instance, they may limit how many concurrent requests that your web server can cope with, and that in turn will affect the costs of running your service. The usual tools for dealing with those practical issues are:

1. Benchmarking - measuring your performance problem in a standard repeatable way, so you can tell how well you are doing when making improvements. Ruby's `benchmark` standard library is a good place to start with this.
2. Profiling - inspecting which parts of the code are performing badly, so you get some clues on how to fix things. You might look at the gem `ruby-prof` for this.

It takes some research and practice to learn how to do this effectively, and they are very broad subjects, too much for a Stack Overflow answer. If you want to get started, do a web search for "Ruby Benchmarking" or "Rails Profiling". Best to start when you have a practical problem to solve.